# Selected radio button is not being displayed?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Everyone I have radio button ,I want the selected value to be displayed into my 2nd activity. when I put extra and intent it , its not being displayed.
I think I did something wrong or missing something.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.shiva_000.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String Tag_Price ="tag";
    public static final String TAG_Radio ="Button";
    private String SelectedType ="";
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";

    EditText et;

    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    // Radio button
    Button button2;
    RadioGroup radio_g;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;



    static final int cam_request = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        et =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        radio_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.newoption);
        final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.usedoption);


// on click for submit
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {





                String s = et.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("Condition",SelectedType);
                i.putExtra("Price",s);
               i.putExtra("image",path);


                startActivity(i);



            }
        });


// on click for capture image
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_Intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                camera_Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_Intent, cam_request);

            }

        });


//launchSecondActivity(Double.parseDouble(et.getText().toString()),null);

    }
//private void launchSecondActivity(double price ,Image image){



    // }
    public void Condition(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.newoption:
                if (checked)
                    //SelectedType = rb1.getText().toString();

                    break;
            case R.id.usedoption:
                if (checked)
                   // SelectedType = rb2.getText().toString();

                    break;
        }
    }

    private File getFile()
    {
        File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");

        if (!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File image_file = new File(folder,"cam_image.jpg");
        return image_file;


// return null;

    }


// public void

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
    }

//private void launchSecondActivity(condion , ){

//}
}
```

**secondScreen.java**

```
package com.example.shiva_000.myproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import  android.graphics.Matrix;
// import android.Graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by shiva_000 on 11/18/2015.
 */
public class secondScreen extends Activity {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        textView1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Intent ii = getIntent();
        Bundle b = ii.getExtras();

        if (b!=null) {
            String passed_condition = (String) b.get("Condition");
            String passed_price = (String) b.get("Price");
            //String passed_image = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
            textView1.setText("Condition : " + passed_condition);
            textView2.setText("The price is : " + passed_price + "$");
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            String image = ii.getStringExtra("image");
            File imgFile = new File(image);


            if (imgFile.exists()) {

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Bitmap bi =Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);


                ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

                myImage.setImageBitmap(bi);
            }

            //imageView.setImageDrawable();
        }



        //button.setOnClickListener();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        //String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("")






    }




  //  private void initializesecondactivity ()
    //{
       // double price = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble(MainActivity.Tag_Price);

   // }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to SellJunky"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:textColor="#a91b1b"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture Image"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Condition"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:id="@+id/rg1">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newoption"
            android:text="@string/New"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:onClick="Condition"
            />
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/usedoption"
            android:text="@string/Used"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:onClick="Condition"
            />


    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/submit"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="437dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.16" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Condition : "
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price : "
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Finished"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't understand what u are trying to do here could u explain more?

Comment: because you didn't set value into `SelectedType`, you've commented the two lines

Comment: the radio button has new and used option to choose from and the selected value should be displayed into the 2nd activity

Comment: if i put it there, it crashes the program @cwfei

Comment: help me @Tony. do u understand the problem now?

Comment: please post your xml

Comment: yes please post the layout i couldn't get ur problem from the code

Comment: @cwfei i have posted the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occur because you didn't set the listener for `RadioGroup` correctly.

```
// First, set onCheckChangeListener into your RadioGroup
radio_g.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rGroup, int checkedId)
    {
       // find view for both radio buttons
        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)rGroup.findViewById(R.id.newoption);
        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)rGroup.findViewById(R.id.usedoption);


        if (rb1.isChecked()) {
            SelectedType = rb1.getText().toString(); // set text into SelectedType 
        } else if (rb2.isChecked()) {
            SelectedType = rb2.getText().toString();
           }

    }
});
```

Comment: do i have to import anything for this or no? i copied and pasted this, and i am getting some errors

Comment: yes, you need to import some native listener libraries, just hit `Alt + Enter` if you're using `Android Studio`

Comment: the app crahses due to that if and else staatements. thats why i had them commened out. its making the app crash

Comment: 11-18 22:42:21.623 11450-11450/com.example.shiva_000.myproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
11-18 22:42:21.623 11450-11450/com.example.shiva_000.myproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
11-18 22:42:21.623 11450-11450/com.example.shiva_000.myproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913) 
11-18 22:42:21.623 11450-11450/com.example.shiva_000.myproject E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)

Comment: try remove the `onClick` method from both your radio buttons in your xml files

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    package com.example.shiva_000.myproject;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URI;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String Tag_Price ="tag";
    public static final String TAG_Radio ="Button";
    private String SelectedType ="";
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
    EditText et;
    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    // Radio button
    Button button2;
    RadioGroup radio_g;
    RadioButton rb1;
    static final int cam_request = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imageView =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        et =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        radio_g=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);

        int selectedId=radio_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
        SelectedType = rb1.getText().toString();
        // on click for submit
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s = et.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,secondScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("Condition",SelectedType);
                i.putExtra("Price",s);
                i.putExtra("image",path);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // on click for capture image
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent camera_Intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file = getFile();
                camera_Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_Intent, cam_request);
            }
        });
    }

    private File getFile()
    {
        File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");
        if (!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        File image_file = new File(folder,"cam_image.jpg");
        return image_file;
    }
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       // String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
       imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
    }
}
```